# FitNesse test returns "Class RunEtlFixture is not a fixture"

Tags: java, fitnesse

I set up FitNesse locally, and I'm trying to run a test, using my own java code.

Here is the Fixture class:

```
import fit.ColumnFixture;

public class RunEtlFixture
{
   private String etlName;
   private int numOfInputRecords;
   private int numOfOutputRecords;

   public void setEtlName(String etlName) {
      this.etlName = etlName;
   }

   public void setNumberOfInputRecords(int num){
      this.numOfInputRecords = num;
   }

}
```

And here is the test wiki:

```
<test page>

!path /Users/shay/Projects/AMP/Talend Jobs Testing/FitNesseTests

| RunEtlFixture                          |
| EtlName | InputRecords | OutputRecords |
| etl_one | 5            | 5             |
| etl_two | 10           | 10            |
```

However, when I run the test, I get:

> Class RunEtlFixture is not a fixture.

I tried searching for help online, but it seems the FitNesse resources are very few. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I was missing is extending the proper fixture:

```
public class RunEtlFixture extends ColumnFixture {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is to define the following in your sub-wiki:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
```